# user limit (128) on the number of inotify instances has been reached

Tags: .net, linux, inotify

I am using `Ubuntu 22.04` to run `.net 6` projects. When I run 2 or 3 projects simultaneously, I got this error:

```
System.IO.IOException: The configured user limit (128) on the number of inotify instances has been reached, or the per-process limit on the number of open file descriptors has been reached.
```

It a long term that I run `.net` on `Ubuntu` and I have encountered this before, but cannot remember how I had solved this. The complete stack trace as is:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: The configured user limit (128) on the number of inotify instances has been reached, or the per-process limit on the number of open file descriptors has been reached.
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents()
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEventsIfNotDisposed()
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_EnableRaisingEvents(Boolean value)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFilesWatcher.TryEnableFileSystemWatcher()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFilesWatcher.CreateFileChangeToken(String filter)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider.Watch(String filter)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.<.ctor>b__1_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider..ctor(FileConfigurationSource source)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationSource.Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at xyz
   at xyz
   at xyz/Program.cs:line 14
```

**UPDATE 1:**

it is the result of `ulimit -a`:

```
real-time non-blocking time  (microseconds, -R) unlimited
core file size              (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size               (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority                 (-e) 0
file size                   (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                     (-i) 27297
max locked memory           (kbytes, -l) 882152
max memory size             (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                          (-n) 1024
pipe size                (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues         (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority                  (-r) 0
stack size                  (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time                   (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes                  (-u) 27297
virtual memory              (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                          (-x) unlimited
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I have used several wrok-arounds so far. But, finally this one resolved my issue:

echo fs.inotify.max_user_instances=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p

this is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60727988/167670).

Comment: `ulimit` sets user limits

Comment: `ulimit` says it is `unlimited`

Comment: Which limit did you check?

Comment: @stark Please see the update 1