# Error Debugging in VS Code: Cannot connect to the target at localhost:3000: could not find any debuggable target

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, vscode-debugger, launch, javascript-debugger

I have an application with React on frontend and .Net Core on backend and i am trying to debug my react frontend, without extensions and attaching to the process, but i am getting the message error bellow:

> Cannot connect to the target at localhost:3000: Could not connect to debug target at http:localhost:3000: Could not find any debuggable target.

I'm using this `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug FrontEnd",
            "port": 3000,
            "request": "attach",
            "type": "chrome",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug BackEnd",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}
```

I start my frontend using `npm start` witch is basically `react-scripts start`.

Obs.: Iḿ using opera browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround.
This problem only occurs when I run with `sudo npm start`.
When running it with just `npm start` I got this message:

*"Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: The configured user limit (128) on the number of inotify instances has been reached, or the per-process limit on the number of open file descriptors has been reached."*

So I solved it increasing the fs.inotify.max_user_instances with this command:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_instances=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

I found this solution by the answer of @Creak . To see more details, click [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469400/asp-net-core-the-configured-user-limit-128-on-the-number-of-inotify-instance)

Answer (score 1):

After a search, all I could found was [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug-core/issues/376).

Although Opera is now based on Chromium, it's not possible to debug it using VSCode yet. Maybe someone can come with a kind of workaround for it.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78052455/4630229).

The issue can be solved by setting environment variable DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER to true.